# Using A* search algorithm to solve 3x3 three-dimensional box puzzle?

Tags: c, algorithm, search, a-star

I am working on a 3x3 three-dimensional box puzzle problem in my homework. I will code with C.

[image: Image of the puzzle]

There are 26 boxes and at first, first place is empty. By sliding boxes I must arrange them in correct order. Red numbers shows correct order and 27th place must be empty at last. I do not want you to give me code; I searched in forums and it seems that I must use the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), but how?

Can you give me tips about how I can use the A* algorithm on this problem? What type of data structure should I use?

Comment: The A* algorithm is a path-finding algorithm. Could you clarify if you are trying to make the user or the program solve the puzzle? If it's the user, then I can't see how you would use A*. But if it's the program, perhaps you could think of the space as the object that moves around, needing the path-finding.

Comment: The program will solve the problem and every step, every movement of box must be written to console. Could you explain more clearly please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Define your problem as a states-graph:

`G=(V,E)` where `V=S={(x_1,x_2,...,x_54) | all possible states the 3d board can be in}` [each number is representing a single 'square' on the 3d board].

and define `E={(v1,v2)| it is possible to move from state v1 to state v2 with a single step}` an alternative definition [identical] for `E` is by using the function `successors(v)`:

For each v in V: `successors(v)={all possible boards you can get, with 1 step from v}`

You will also need an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), a pretty good one for this problem can be: `h(state)=Sigma(manhattan_distance(x_i)) where i in range [1,54])` basically, it is the summation of [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) for each number from its target.

Now, once we got this data, we can start running A* on the defined graph G, with the defined heuristic. And since our heuristic function is admissible [convince yourself why!], it is guaranteed that the solution A* finds will be optimal, due to [admissibility and optimality of A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality).

Finding the actual path: A* will end when you develop the target state. [`x_i=i` in the terms we used earlier]. You will find your path to it by stepping back from the target to the source, using the `parent` field in each node.

Comment: Thank you fo your answer. I couldn' understand that why you described V==S from 1 to 54? I mean why 54?

Comment: @hasan: there are 9 tiles in each [face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(geometry)) of the cube. Since a cube has 6 faces, and `6*9=54`, there are total of 54 tiles in the entire puzzle.

Comment: Ok but i couldn't understant the point that why we interested in faces? We are not concerned with this, aren't we?

Comment: @hasan: we do not care about the faces, but we care about the final position of each tile/number, it has to form a specific shape. I refered to the 'faces' only to explain why we have 54 tiles [x_1,...,x_54].

Answer (score 3):

You know how graphs work and how A* finds shortest paths on them, right?

The basic idea is that each configuration of the puzzle can be considered a vertex in a graph and the edges represent the moves (by connecting the configurations before and after the move).

Finding a set of moves that leads from an original configuration to a desired one can be seen as a path finding problem.